# SQL Insert where ID is, plus a static string

Tags: php, mysql

I've had a look around but I can't quite seem to find what I'm looking for. I know this is probably completely wrong and the answer is most likely something simple, but I can't work it out. I'm still quite new to MySQL queries so any help would be fantastic.

I have this

```
INSERT INTO bitnami_wordpress.wp_usermeta_new (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT `UserID`, VALUE(`phone_number`),`telephone_number`
FROM my_db.userinfo
```

As you can see, I have a VALUE there. I'm trying to make that part a static string to be inserted into 'meta_key', so that it is placed something like

```
user_id - meta_key     - meta_Value
1       - phone_number - 01234567890
1       - fav_colour   - red
```

So the user_id and telephone_number are brought from the table, but the VALUE is a static piece of text. I'm basically trying to convert a table to WP via several MySQL queries in PHPMyAdmin. I'll be doing the same thing for several other fields such as fav_colour (just an example).

Comment: `SELECT UserID, VALUE('phone_number')` is wrong. `VALUE` is used for `INSERT`, not for `SELECT`. Delect `VALUE` and it'll work

Comment: Just put a string literal there `SELECT UserID, 'phone_number' ,telephone_number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query should look like:

```
INSERT INTO bitnami_wordpress.wp_usermeta_new (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT `UserID`, 'phone_number',`telephone_number`
FROM my_db.userinfo
```

You only need single quotes arround the static string.

Comment: Ahh so it was something silly on my part. Thanks a lot for the fast solution!